# NETWORK_AVAILABILITY

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

**I have this code

```
**package com.example.pay;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.paypal.checkout.PayPalCheckout;
import com.paypal.checkout.approve.Approval;
import com.paypal.checkout.approve.OnApprove;
import com.paypal.checkout.config.CheckoutConfig;
import com.paypal.checkout.config.Environment;
import com.paypal.checkout.createorder.CreateOrder;
import com.paypal.checkout.createorder.CreateOrderActions;
import com.paypal.checkout.createorder.CurrencyCode;
import com.paypal.checkout.createorder.OrderIntent;
import com.paypal.checkout.createorder.UserAction;
import com.paypal.checkout.order.Amount;
import com.paypal.checkout.order.AppContext;
import com.paypal.checkout.order.CaptureOrderResult;
import com.paypal.checkout.order.OnCaptureComplete;
import com.paypal.checkout.order.OrderRequest;
import com.paypal.checkout.order.PurchaseUnit;
import com.paypal.checkout.paymentbutton.PayPalButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CheckBox c;
    EditText pass;

    PayPalButton paymentButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isNetworkAvailable = activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
        Toast.makeText(this, isNetworkAvailable+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        paymentButton = findViewById(R.id.payment_button_container);
        try {
            CheckoutConfig config1= new CheckoutConfig(getApplication(),
                    "AYG_TzAFlUvFiW5hXvR15H9LI65ia3VTj7SQHQ6uxS5Ciqeditf4ZcHQ7F7ABrR2vqnFEa4K9AhYa2YC",
                    Environment.SANDBOX,CurrencyCode.USD,"com.example.pay://paypalpay");

            PayPalCheckout.setConfig(config1);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getLocalizedMessage() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


        paymentButton.setup(new CreateOrder() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void create(@NonNull CreateOrderActions createOrderActions) {
                                             ArrayList p = new ArrayList();
                                             p.add(new PurchaseUnit.Builder().amount(new Amount.Builder()
                                                             .currencyCode(CurrencyCode.USD).value("10").build())

                                                     .build());
                                             OrderRequest o = new OrderRequest(OrderIntent.CAPTURE, new AppContext.Builder()
                                                     .userAction(UserAction.PAY_NOW).build(), p);
                                             createOrderActions.create(o, (CreateOrderActions.OnOrderCreated) null);

                                         }
                                     }, new OnApprove() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onApprove(@NonNull Approval approval) {
                                             approval.getOrderActions().capture(new OnCaptureComplete() {
                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onCaptureComplete(@NonNull CaptureOrderResult captureOrderResult) {
                                                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OnCaptureComplete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                 }
                                             });

                                         }
                                     }

        );
    }

}
```

When a ring is made, the button loads endlessly, and these errors appear during playback

```
E/nxoEvents: fire: No one listening to the event of type NETWORK_AVAILABILITY.
```

---

I want a solution to this problem or any method of paying by PayPal in the Java language

**.................**.....................................................................................................